# asp.net global.asax Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I have a site with multiple domains pointing to it. I wanted to redirect all requests to main domain so I've created a method called RedirectToRealDomain("domain.com") to check and redirect all requests to my preferred domain

At the moment it lives on Session_Start but I am planing to move it to Application_BeginRequest event.

Is that good idea? As I understand Session_Start only raised when new session started but Application_BeginRequest raised on all requests. RedirectToRealDomain method doesn't do any DB lookups or anything expensive apart from comparing strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will work.  I use an HTTP module's "BeginRequest" event to do the same thing on my site.

Another option is to create a 2nd IIS site and point all of the other domains to this site.  Then you can use the IIS management console to redirect all requests to the 1st site.

Comment: Great minds think alike. +1.  (Not that my mind is really all that great, but you know the saying...)

Comment: @David do you mean putting RedirectToRealDomain to Application_BeginRequest instead of Session_Start would be better?

Comment: I guess I was ambiguous.  I've edited the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, but there are other non-programming ways of doing this from within IIS, which I presume would be less overhead and probably a more "correct" way of doing it.  Your understanding of when the events are raised is correct, though and your solution should work and not be too much of a server drain.

See here for how to do it in IIS:

http://www.getfoundnow.com/iis_301_redirect.htm

Comment: I know but i wanted to create a set and forget solution. with iis if i move site i would have to setup evrything again.

Comment: OK.  Then proceed with plan A.  Put it in the Applicaiton_BeginRequest.